# MVC 3, Divs and CSS ids issue

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a simple partial view that shows the result of an action and displays the message to use either success or failure. The partial view is rendered from inside the main view.

However the css styling is not working if I want to use a specific css ID for a div tag. If I apply a class then the style works. eg

The partial view looks:

```
@Code
ViewData("Title") = "Results"

If Model.Result = True Then
    @<div id="success">@Model.Message</div>
Else
    @<div id="notsuccess">@Model.Message</div>
End If
```

End Code

the line         @@Model.Message somehow does not work.  The CSS is like:

```
#success {
background-color:Lime;
font-style:italic;
font-size:larger;
```

}

```
#notsuccess {
background-color:Red;
font-style:italic;
font-size:larger;
```

}

However, if I change the css to be .success and change the line to use the .success class instead of id then it shows the styling. Can anyone please point me to issue?

I am using the default MVC project for MVC 3.

Comment: It would help if you also pasted the generated HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely there is another div named #success.  You'll need to paste/inspect the complete HTML view of the page.